# This is the error I am facing while sending the mail function

Tags: module, email, custom

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;


class Index extends Action
{
    private $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */

    protected $context;
  //  private $fileUploaderFactory;
    private $fileSystem;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        //\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Eaglerocket\Customquote\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
      //  $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
       // $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('upload_document');

       

        $txt='<table>';

       
        if($post['comment']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $txt.='</table>';
        //echo $txt;



        $customerName='Demo Form';
        $message=$txt;

        $userSubject= 'Demo From ';     
        $fromEmail= 'kirti003shukla@gmail.com';
        $fromName = 'Test Demo Form';

         $templateVars = [
                    'store' => 1,
                    'customer_name' => $customerName,
                    'subject' => $userSubject,
                    'message'   => $message
                ];
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();


        $to = 'kirti.bhumca2015@gmail.com';     

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(5, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
            //    ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)               
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('post_requirements');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/* generated/*
```

[Magento 2 permission issue for cache folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167554/magento-2-permission-issue-for-cache-folder)

Comment: Errors during compilation:Eaglerocket\Customquote\Controller\Index\Index Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig. File: /var/www/demo/app/code/Eaglerocket/Customquote

Comment: new error when run the command s:d:c

Comment: Share your code Please @kks

Comment: post your controller code in question